# Is this SSO workflow possible?

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, saml

Let's say I have the following sites: ClientSiteA.com, ClientSiteB.com, ClientSiteC.com, MainServer.com

I am distributing a software to client sites. Anyone will be able to install the software so a site can not be considered trusted. MainServer.com will contain user information.

Users will interact with the software on client sites. A user will be able to click a login link on any client site which will bring up a popup. The popup can reside on MainServer.com. When a user logs in on any client, they will be logged in on ALL client sites as well as the MainServer.com. Remember, MainServer.com contains all user information.

I've done a lot of reading on SAML and OAuth2. Can someone tell me what is possible? If it is possible, which tools/workflows should I use? If this isn't possible, can someone tell me something I can accomplish that is similar to this?

FYI - I am trying to accomplish something like what Disqus does. If you login to Disqus on any site, you are logged into all the sites.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: ???? I could really use some help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with SAML, although it will involve browser redirects not popups.

The first time use hits a protected site (ClientA) it redirects to MainServer.com.  The user logs in, MainServer gives them a session and redirects them back to the service provider with a SAML authentication statement which then lets them in.

When the user then visits ClientB.com, it also redirects to MainServer.com for authentication.  Because the user is already logged at MainServer it can invisibly bounce them straight back to ClientB.com with a new authentication statement.  The user barely if at all notices.

The problem with the pop-up window approach is that users have to give their credentials for site A to site B.  This is a big security hole if site B isn't owned and controlled by Site A.  Users should only give their credentials to the site that is authenticating them to prevent them being compromised.  SAML and other federated/distributed auth mechanisms were designed with that in mind.  I wouldn't want to give the keys to my email account to random sites on the internet but with this method I can log into stackoverflow with my gmail account.

Comment: So let's say a user visits ClientA, goes to login, is redirected to MainServer, then redirected back to ClientA. How does ClientA know that the user is logged in?

That same user having logged in to ClientA, visits ClientB. How does ClientB know the user is logged in?

I thought SAML only involved trusted sites? Since this software is distributed freely, client sites aren't trust.

Comment: ClientA knows user is logged in because when MainServer sends the user back it sends them with an signed authentication statement to say so.  It's the same for ClientB.   In this scenario trust is established using X509 certificates and XML signatures.

Comment: So when a logged in user (from Client A) visits Client B, does another redirect have to occur? Do you have any links on this? Any more information?

Comment: Look up the SAML HTTP Redirect binding and the SAML HTTP Post binding.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0  They're used by the Web Browser SSO Profile.  HTH.

Comment: Would it be possible to do a popup where the popup lives on the secure main site?

Comment: Also, instead of doing the redirect can't I just use window.postMessage to send the SAML token or whatever from the popup back to the main window?

Comment: Tom can you ping me on Twitter? @tlovett12